# what does it mean when you HAVE to provide UV coordinates using a Texture Coordinate node (to apply materials)?

Tags: uv

I imported a mesh from an .obj file, and I can't apply materials to it without providing UV coordinates using a Texture Coordinate node. It would just show up black when rendered.

[image]
[image]

what does this mean? Because, I've noticed when I add a Suzanne head (or any primitive mesh) and unwrap it, I don't have to add a Texture Coordinate node to apply materials to it.

thanks :]

Answer (score 1):

You don't normally connect a *UV* socket to a *Normal* socket, the *Normal* socket is generally used for displacement or bump type of effects using either a texture or a normal map.

The fact that you connecting the *UV* socket to the *Normal* input of the material worked is probably just a coincidence, and a side effect of the fact that you mesh probably has some sort of geometrical glitch or wrong facing normals.

Try entering edit mode and clearing or recalculating your normals be selecting all faces and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and see if that solves the problem.

Have in mind that this may destroy any custom normals your model might have (if any).